# Why won't PPSSPP load my state on a different computer account?

Tags: emulation, ppsspp

I've recently installed PPSSPP to play Fate/Extra, and so far so good. Today I logged into another computer account to use, but the emulator won't find my save data for the game, nor will it find my save state for it. To my memory, other emulators i've used in the past (DeSmuMe, etc.) have not had the same issue, but I don't know the difference with using iso files. The emulator itself was installed to my external drive for efficiency and not to take up too much space on my hard drive.

Comment: I'm assuming it's saving the savefiles in your user profile (Documents or similar). There will probably be a path in the settings you can change. Check `PPSSPP/memstick/PSP/SAVEDATA` to see if your files are there. If they are, then I'm not sure what could be going on.

Comment: Is it from the same version of PPSSPP?